# C - unable to edit or print char array

Tags: c, arrays, string

Newbie question here... How am I supposed to properly deal with mutable char arrays that represent strings when I'm in a function? I'm doing this

```
char temp[BASE10LENGTH_DEGREE_DECIMALS+1]; //aka length of 7
memset(temp, 0, sizeof(temp));
```

As you can see, it has that null-terminator in there. But if I do something like this

```
temp[i] = '1'; //when i = 0
```

then call atoi() on temp, I get 0. EDIT 2: No I don't! But I still can't print it in the debugger.

Also, if I look at the debugger, temp does not expand into an array, and using lldb's print feature on it gives me this

```
(lldb) print temp
error: incomplete type 'char []' where a complete type is required
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

It works if I use a char* and malloc it, but that's not what I want to do. I want just a char array. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here's the whole method. input is "3, 4, 5", and len is 7:
EDIT 2: Actually, the problem with atoi was because I messed up those if statements by putting in less than 9 and greater than 0 instead of less than '9' and greater than '0'... Careless error.

```
struct Coordinates{
unsigned int longitude;
unsigned int latitude;
unsigned short altitude;
};

struct Coordinates* getCoordinatesFromString(char* input, int len){ 
struct Coordinates* ret = malloc(sizeof(struct Coordinates));

char temp[BASE10LENGTH_DEGREE_DECIMALS+1];
memset(temp, '\0', sizeof(temp));
int i = 0; int i2 = 0; char currentChar;
while (input[i]!=','){
    if (i>=len)
        return NULL; //out of bounds error
    currentChar = input[i];
    if ((currentChar>=0 && currentChar<=9) || currentChar=='.') temp[i2] = currentChar;
    i++;
    i2++;
}
ret->latitude = atoi(temp);
memset(temp, 0, sizeof(temp));
i++; i2 = 0;
while (input[i]!=','){
    if (i>=len)
        return NULL; //out of bounds error
    currentChar = input[i];
    if ((currentChar>=0 && currentChar<=9) || currentChar=='.') temp[i2] = currentChar;
    i++;
    i2++;
}
ret->longitude = atoi(temp); //keeps giving me zero
memset(temp, 0, sizeof(temp));
i++; i2 = 0;
while (input[i]!=','){
    if (i>=len)
        break;
    currentChar = input[i];
    if ((currentChar>=0 && currentChar<=9) || currentChar=='.') temp[i2] = currentChar;
    i++;
    i2++;
}
ret->altitude = atoi(temp);
memset(temp, 0, sizeof(temp));

return ret;
}
```

Comment: You need to show us a [small complete program](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem. I just copy-and-pasted your code into a small program, and `atoi(temp)` correctly returned `1`. See http://ideone.com/HrByzB

Comment: Is `temp` a local variable or a function parameter?

Comment: temp is a local variable, just declared inside that function.

Comment: [Works fine for me?](http://codepad.org/X65JMVAL)

Comment: In your comparison here: `if ((currentChar>=0 && currentChar<=9)`, do you mean `if ((currentChar>='0' && currentChar<='9')`? I'm guessing that `tmp` is empty because the condition is never true. `If the first sequence of non-whitespace characters in str is not a valid integral number, or if no such sequence exists because either str is empty or it contains only whitespace characters, no conversion is performed and zero is returned.` That would explain why your output is zero.

Comment: @remyabel Oops, yeah that's a mistake. Still, I don't understand why it's not letting me print the array as a string.

Comment: @9000 You mean in the debugger? Or using a printf statement?

Comment: @ccKep In your example, you initialize the array with 7 instead of a variable like I did. I can print it in the compiler if I do it that way (I just tried it), but not the way I did it. But atoi and everything still work anyway, so it's not a serious problem.

Comment: @remyabel Debugger. Just tried it, and printf does work with it. Actually everything in my program seems fine for now, but the debugger has issues with my code.

Comment: @9000 Can you try `expr (int)printf("%s", temp)`. I have no experience with lldb so I don't know.

Comment: @9000 I thought that was just a #define - my bad

Comment: @remyabel That works. Prints out a "1" for me. It seems that lldb's print function just doesn't work with variable-sized arrays.

Answer (score 1):

When you find a comma, you're skipping over the comma (`++i`), but the next input character in your input is a space, so `temp[0]` ends up with a null character, which means `atoi()` will return 0.  You need to skip over the comma AND the space.

Alternatively, if your input string is null-terminated, you can simplify your code by using the `strtok()` function that is part of the C run-time library.  Example:

```
#include <string.h>

struct Coordinates* getCoordinatesFromString(char* input)
{ 
    struct Coordinates* ret = malloc(sizeof(struct Coordinates));
    int part = 0;

    if (ret != NULL) {
        char *s = strtok(input, ",");
        while (s != NULL && part < 3) {
            int value = atoi(s);

            switch(++part) {
                case 1:
                    ret->latitude = value;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ret->longitude = value;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    ret->altitude = value;
                    break;
            }

            s = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }

        /* if input was not valid, return NULL */
        if (part < 3) {
            free(ret);
            ret = NULL;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: You're right. I didn't have time to look at it more, but that explains why it's only getting the first coordinate. I still can't get it to print with the debugger, but I'm not worried about that very much... just a little curious.